# Closed Form Matrix Square Root

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

## Problem Statement

Given $\mu, \lambda \in\mathbb{R}$ the identity matrix $I$ and a vector $x$ whose unnormalized version is $\hat{x} = x/\|x\|$ we are told that the square root of
$$
A = \frac{1}{\|x\|^2}\left[\mu^2 I + (\lambda^2-\mu^2)\hat{x}\hat{x}\top\right]
$$
is simply
$$
A^{1/2} = \frac{1}{\|x\|}\left[\mu I + (\lambda -\mu)\hat{x}\hat{x}^\top\right].
$$
Given a matrix $S=L^\top L$ we are now asked to find (if it exists in closed form) the matrix square root of
$$
B= \frac{1}{x^\top Sx}\left[\mu^2 S + (\lambda^2-\mu^2)\frac{S x x^\top S^\top}{x^\top S x}\right].
$$

## Questions

> 1. What is $B^{1/2}$?
> 2. Is there a general technique to matrix square roots when they are available in closed form?

## Attempt

First, I write $B$ explicitly using $L$
$$
B = \frac{1}{x^\top L^\top Lx}\left[\mu^2 L^\top L + (\lambda^2-\mu^2)\frac{L^\top L x x^\top L^\top L}{x^\top L^\top L x}\right]
$$
Then I introduce the following notation to simplify thing $y = Lx$ so that we have
$$
B = \frac{1}{\|y\|^2}\left[\mu^2 L^\top L + (\lambda^2-\mu^2)L^\top \hat{y} \hat{y}^\top L\right]
$$
But then I am not sure what to do.

AHHH perhaps
$$
B^{1/2} = \frac{1}{\|y\|}\left[\mu L + (\lambda-\mu)\hat{y} \hat{y}^\top L\right]
$$

Let's check:
$$
\begin{align}
    (B^{1/2})^\top B^{1/2} 
&= \frac{1}{\|y\|^2}\left[\mu L + (\lambda-\mu)\hat{y} \hat{y}^\top L\right]^\top \left[\mu L + (\lambda-\mu)\hat{y} \hat{y}^\top L\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{\|y\|^2}\left[\mu^2 L^\top L +  2\mu (\lambda-\mu) L^\top\hat{y}\hat{y}^\top L + (\lambda-\mu)^2 L^\top \hat{y}\hat{y}^\top L\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{\|y\|^2}\left[\mu^2 L^\top L + (\lambda^2-\mu^2)L^\top \hat{y}\hat{y}^\top L\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{x^\top S x}\left[\mu^2 S + (\lambda^2-\mu^2)\frac{Sxx^\top S^\top}{x^\top S x}\right] \\
&= B
\end{align}
$$
This took me a while. But is there a method to do this? For me it was just lots of trial and error.

Comment: By a "square root" $X$ of a matrix $Y$ , do you mean a decomposition $Y=X^TX$, a true square root (a matrix $X$ such that $X^2=Y$) or even a positive semidefinite square root ($Y=X^2$ and $X$ is positive semidefinite)? The $A^{1/2}$ you give is a positive semidefinite square root of $A$, but the "$B^{1/2}$" you produce is not a true square root of $B$, although $B$ is the Gramian of your $B^{1/2}$.

Comment: @user1551 I am not sure.. Wait why is $B^{1/2}$ not a square root of $B$?

Comment: Because its square is not $B$.

Comment: http://montypython.50webs.com/scripts/Holy_Grail/Scene22.htm   ;;;;;; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0D7hFHfLEyk

Comment: @user1551 I'm so confused. Is my calculation above wrong?

Comment: It isn't wrong, but what you showed is that the Gramian of your $B^{1/2}$ is $B$, not that the square of $B^{1/2}$ is $B$.

Comment: @user1551 ooh I see now!! $B^{1/2} B^{1/2}$ versus $(B^{1/2})^\top B^{1/2}$

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked what do you mean by a "square root".

Comment: If you assume that $L$ is symmetric, then $B$ is the square root and you're done.  If it's not symmetric, then replace the $L$'s in $B$ with the square root $S^{1/2}-$ which you'll need to calculate yourself.